# ASP.NET vNext Core CLR missing type.IsPrimitive

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to migrate a web app to ASP.Net vNext with the eventual aim of getting it running on Linux.

The app has a lot of reflection code and I must be missing some dependencies as I am getting compile errors on code such as this

> Type.IsPrimitive, Type.GetConstructor Type.GetMethod Type.GetTypeArray
>   Error   CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsPrimitive' and no extension method 'IsPrimitive' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error  CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod' and no extension method 'GetMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error  CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error  CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetInterface' and no extension method 'GetInterface' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have the following dependencies in my project.json files

```
"frameworks" : {
    "aspnetcore50" : { 
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22416",
            "System.Linq": "4.0.0.0-beta-22605",
            "System.Reflection": "4.0.10.0-beta-22605",
            "System.Reflection.Primitives": "4.0.0.0-beta-22605",
            "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.10.0-beta-22605",
            "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.0.0-beta-22605"
        }
```

The following compiles fine under VS 2013 and .Net 4.5 but wont compile in VS 2015 using the dependencies above

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;


namespace Project1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            Type lBaseArrayType = typeof(Array);
            Type lStringType = typeof(string);
            string[] lStringArray = new string[1];
            if (lStringType.IsPrimitive)
            {
            }
            ConstructorInfo lConstructor = lStringType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
            MethodInfo lMethod = lStringType.GetMethod("Equals");
            Type[] lTArray = Type.GetTypeArray(lStringArray);
            PropertyInfo[] lProps = lStringType.GetProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your relevant code? Preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It might be as simple as you're missing some using statements, but it's hard to know unless you show us the code.

Comment: Below is a sample piece of code, it doesn't do anything but is just a selection of the methods I am trying to call

Comment: I looked through the source code on GitHub and couldn't find those methods. Perhaps that's just one of the things they haven't yet implemented for .NET CORE? You can keep from compiling that stuff with compiler directives in .NET 5 (non-CORE).

Comment: Just FYI...you can http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/ to figure out the nuget packages which has the API that you are looking for...this can help in migration..

Answer (score 21):

If you're using aspnetcore .IsPrimitive is available, but not as a member of Type. You'll find it under TypeInfo, which can be accessed by calling the `GetTypeInfo()` method of Type. In your example, it would be:

```
lStringType.GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive
```

`Type.GetMethod()` is also available, but you'll need to reference the `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` package in your `project.json` file.

`Type.GetTypeArray()` is missing, but you can easily write a simple linq query to retrieve an array of member types in the array.

`Type.GetInterface()` is not included, but again using `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` will expose another method that generates a `Type[]` of all implemented interfaces for the type specified.

```
Type[] types = Type.GetInterfaces()
```

`Type.GetProperties()` is available again through the `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` library.

Comment: But these methods are not available in .NET Core only in DNX

Comment: You'll need to add `using System.Reflection;` to get access to `GetTypeInfo()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static method `System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo()` to get the same information.

```
    var arrayType = typeof(Array);
    var stringType = typeof(string);
    var stringArray = new string[1];
    var stringTypeInfo = stringType.GetTypeInfo();
    if (stringTypeInfo.IsPrimitive)
    {
    }

    ConstructorInfo lConstructor = stringTypeInfo.DeclaredConstructors.Where(x => x.GetParameters().Any() == false).FirstOrDefault();
    MethodInfo lMethod = stringTypeInfo.DeclaredMethods.Where(x => x.Name == "Equals").FirstOrDefault();
    Type[] lTArray = stringArray.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct().ToArray();
    PropertyInfo[] lProps = stringTypeInfo.DeclaredProperties.ToArray();
```